# Replace content of select2 dropdown with data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have a rails app with two dropdown. When the first one is selected "author", it makes a ajax call to retrieve author's book. The autour book call.

In the javascript I have : `$.ajax(type: 'GET', url: myadress)`.

It renders a `.js.erb` file :

```
var dropdown = "<%= escape_javascript(select_tag :author_book, options_from_collection_for_select(@books, :id, :serial), id: 'serial') %>";
var nextDiv = $('#author_book').next();
if(nextDiv.hasClass('select2')) {
    nextDiv.remove();
}
$('#author_book').remove();
$('#author').next().after(dropdown);
$('#author_book').select2();
```

The haml file looks like this :

```
#author
  = simple_form_for :author, url: author_path(store_id: current_store), html: {method: 'post', remote: true, id: nil, class: 'none'} do |f|

    #left-scheduled_publications-form
      = f.input_field :authors, collection: authors, required: true

      %br
      = select_tag :author_book, options_for_select([], params[:author_book]), required: true
```

But it break my dom and it's really ugly. [It seems their is an issue related](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830) but maybe I'm wrong.

What is a better way to handle this ? Is it possible to replace the data more easily ?

Comment: Too less information to answer this question. You need to paste your HTML code as well.

Comment: thanks @ArslanAli. I add it.

Answer (score 1):

Put your second select in a partial:

**_author_book.haml.erb**

```
= select_tag :author_book, options_from_collection_for_select(@books, :id, :serial), id: 'serial')
```

Add an enclosing `div` in your view for the dynamic content:

```
#author
  = simple_form_for :author, url: author_path(store_id: current_store), html: {method: 'post', remote: true, id: nil, class: 'none'} do |f|

    #left-scheduled_publications-form
      = f.input_field :authors, collection: authors, required: true

      .author-books
        = select_tag :author_book, options_for_select([], params[:author_book]), required: true
```

In your JS response:

```
$(".author-books").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render: 'author_book') %>");
$('#author_book').select2();
```

Ideally, you'd want to include the partial in the initial rendering of the form as well, which you could do by setting `@books` to an empty array.

Comment: Thanks @jaxx, gonna try to implement it.

Comment: You're very welcome. Let me know if you have any issues so I can help & edit the answer. Good luck!